# Spring Integration 2 Phase Commit

Tags: spring-integration

Below is our `IntegrationFlow`, kindly suggest how 2-phase commit or best-efforts 1-phase commit can be implemented for the 2 databases involved. Thanks

`MQ` Adapter --> `Jpa.updatingGateway`(db1) & `Jpa.updatingGateway`(db2)

db1 & db2 operations should commit or rollback together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For two different databases (and I assume for MQ as well) you need to use a `org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager`. It is up to you and your environment to determine how you are going to obtain XA transaction: JNDI from some application server like IBM WebSphere or using [Atomikos](https://www.atomikos.com/Main/WebHome).

Then you configure your JMS Inbound Endpoint to use that transaction manager and all the downstream flow will participate in it, if it is connect with direct channels.

Your two `Jpa.updatingGateway()` can be subscribed to the same `PublishSubscribeChannel` or you can use a `routeToRecipients()`.

For example:

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow jmsMessageDrivenRedeliveryFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlow
                .from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(mqFactory)
                        .destination("myQueue")
                        .configureListenerContainer(c -> c.transactionManager(jtaTransactionManager)))
                .publishSubscribeChannel(publishSubscribeSpec -> publishSubscribeSpec
                        .subscribe(subFlow1 -> subFlow1.handle(Jpa.updatingGateway(db1)))
                        .subscribe(subFlow2 -> subFlow2.handle(Jpa.updatingGateway(db2))))
                .get();
    }
```

Comment: Thanq, so I just need to have a common `JtaTransactionManager` and share it along with my MQ and 2 different databases? I don't see `.handle(Jpa.updatingGateway..., ec -> ec.transactional()`. Isn't it required for the DB subscribers?

Comment: You need only one TX manager on the input if your flow. Therefore that `c.transactionManager()` on the `Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter()`. Those JPA adapters are going to participate in this transaction.